# Multiply cells in Excel if a cell has a more recent date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am currently building an Excel worksheet for managing inventory in a large kitchen and I would like to find the value of the inventory for the most recent day.

Inventory is taken four days a week and each row in the table has a price value. What I am trying to do is multiply the inventory for the most recent day in the row.

So if I put in `6` for `MON` then the value would update to `58.80`.

If I add `4` in `TUE` then the value would change to `39.20`.

[image]

The way I have it set now, it just adds up all the values MON through THU and doesn't give me a daily calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trick to finding the last non-empty cell in a range. It is documented [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell).

Assuming your price is in cell D1 and the four inventory numbers are in H2:K2, you can calculate the last inventory value with this formula:

```
=D2*LOOKUP(2,1/(H2:K2<>""),H2:K2)
```